# Spring Boot Data MongoDB - Repository is null

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I want to develop a little test application using Spring Boot and Spring Data MongoDB. So, in this case, I use default configuration (like localhost:27017/test database) and I try to follow the spring guide (https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/).

I launch my application like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        (new DummyClass()).load();
    }
}
```

The DummyClass is as following:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="dummy")
public class DummyClass {

    private static String url;
    private List<Project> projects;


    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepository projectRepository;


    public void setUrl(String url) {
        DummyClass.url = url;
    }


    @Override
    public void load() {

       // (...) creating some project objects

       projectRepository.deleteAll();
       projectRepository.save(this.projects);
    }    
}
```

When the projectRepository.deleteAll() statement is executed, I receive un NullPointerException.

For information, below the ProjectRepository interface:

```
public interface ProjectRepository extends MongoRepository<Project, String>     
{ 
}
```

And my package structure is:
    com.test.dummy
        Application.java
    com.test.dummy.components
        DummyClass.java
    com.test.dummy.domain
        Project.java
    com.test.dummy.repositories
        ProjectRepository.java

Can you help me to understand my error?

Note: I use Spring Boot 1.4.1 and Mongo 3.2

Comment: Well your Application#run method looks weired. Never seen this before. Can you remove it and retry?
Edit: well this is weired. You are creating an object with new DummyClass(). This contradicts the principles of IoC and DI

Comment: Thanks, you're completely right. Shit happens when having one's nose to the grindstone... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `Application.run()` method you instantiate your DummyClass outside of the Spring context (`new DummyClass()`). This way the

```
@Autowired
private ProjectRepository projectRepository;
```

is not instantiated correctly.

You should inject your `DummyClass` via Spring and not create a new instance of it via its constructor.

Example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Autowired
    DummyClass dummyClass;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
       dummyClass.load();
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, well ... hum hum sorry for the inconvenience ;-)